# autodetect proxy setting linux

Tags: python, proxy, mechanize

I am writing a python app that needs to send and retrieve some information from Internet. I would like to auto-detect the proxy setting (to avoid asking the user to set up the proxy configuration). It seems that [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) can do this on Windows and Mac OsX and not on Unix/Linux.

I need/prefer to use the mechanize module, instead of urllib/urllib2. (It is easier to handle data encoded as "multipart/form-data).

Can the mechanize module auto-detect the proxy setting? If true, it will work on Windows, Mac OsX and Linux?

The following code does not work (I am behind a proxy on Linux), unless I uncomment the fourth line.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
#br.set_proxies({'http': 'myproxy.com:3128'})
br.open('http://www.google.com')
response = br.geturl()
print response
```

I guess this means that mechanize can´t auto-detect proxy setting (or may be I am doing something wrong)

How can I auto-detect the proxy setting on Linux (using python)?

EDIT: added on 9th september

I could confirm that Mechanize autodetects proxy setting on Windows, but not on Linux. 
As [mru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832273/mru) correctly pointed out there is no standardized way under Linux to determine the proxy, so I guess the best solution is to check if the user is using Linux and In that case try to get the proxy settings from http_proxy environment variable or from gconf (for Gnome) or from  kioslaverc (KDE). And if everything fails I will ask the user to provided the correct proxy settings (I think this is a fair solution because on one hand I think most Linux users know what a proxy is and on the other hand at least I tried to make things easier for them :-) )

Comment: JFTR there is no standardized way under linux to determine the proxy. The HTTP_PROXY environment variable (btw. i think it is lowercase) is typically only set for cli programs. If you are using a Desktop environment like KDE/Gnome and using their settings this will not show up under http_proxy

Comment: ok... I have a notebook and I am behind a proxy only at the University, I have Firefox configured to auto-detect the proxy settings (may be I could ask them how they do it :-) ) and I change the proxy setting on a per-app-basis if I need it (for Mendeley and sometimes synaptic)... I guess this means I don´t have a global proxy setting (i.e. HTTP_PROXY=None)

Comment: Firefox does something else it uses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol

Comment: I found this python library http://code.google.com/p/pacparser/ I think could help to do what Firefox does... but I think it not the best solution for me (I want to redistribute the code and keep dependencies to a minimum)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to check the `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable (that's the way `wget` checks if it has to use a proxy). The code could look like this for example:

```
import os
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

proxy = os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY')
if proxy is not None:
    br.set_proxies({'http': proxy})

br.open('http://www.google.com')
response = br.geturl()
print response
```

But this won't work on Windows (I don't know for MacOS as it's UNIX based).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your code and I always get  `os.environ.get('HTTP_PROXY')` returns None

Comment: `urllib` should use `HTTP_PROXY` by itself without explicit `.set_proxies()`.

Comment: BTW I tried the variable HTTP_PROXY using lower and upper case.

Comment: @aloctavodia how do you usually set the proxy on your system?

Comment: I have a notebook and I am behind a proxy only at the University, I have Firefox configured to auto-detect the proxy settings and I change the proxy setting on a per-app-basis... I don´t set the proxy for the system (i.e. HTTP_PROXY=None)... I tried changing the proxy setting using "network proxy" (a Gnome app) and I still get None If I use the command "http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port/ export http_proxy". I get the proxy with your method. I think this is related to the comment of @mru

Comment: I found that mechanize already checks if the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables exists. The problem is that there are other options (not involving those variables) to configure the proxy settings.